# TextView string contents not visible when dynamically creating a tablelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have been sitting over my head since couple of hours but I'm yet to find a solution to this strange issue. My requirement is that I need to dynamically create a table layout with header and contents.

This is the code i use to generate the table layout dynamically.

```
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabContentLayout);
tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tableLayout.removeAllViews();

for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
                Log.d("Rows",rows[i]);
                String row  = rows[i];
                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                tableRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                final String[] cols = row.split(";");

                Log.i(LOG_CLASS, "<<---- Columns count : " + cols.length + " ---->>");

                for (int j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {             
                    final String col = cols[j];                                 
                    TextView columsView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    columsView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_header);
                    columsView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    columsView.setTextColor(color.white);
                    columsView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,15);
                    columsView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    columsView.setText(String.format("%7s", col));
                    Log.d("Cols", String.format("%7s", col));
                    tableRow.addView(columsView);                
                    }
//               tableLayout.addView(tableRow,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

            }

            tableLayout.requestLayout();
```

Where the **rows** is a `String[]` containing entries delimited by **;**

For ex: `Apple;10/25/2013;10/25/2014;Srivatsa`

Latest Update : 
Infact the contents view is faintly visible on the **emulator**.(But this cannot be seen on a phone.) Now all i need is to get the text appear legible on the UI.

[image: Emulator - Screenshot]

Comment: Change your TextView Text Color and check that.

Comment: No change. Changing color doesn't help

Comment: Could the '7' screw it up?  '%7s' - 7 characters and right-justify.

Comment: No Rick. Initially even i assumed this but this issue is something else. Something very basic w.r.t placing of controls on the Layout

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
 TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabContentLayout);
        tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tableLayout.removeAllViews();

        for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
            Log.d("Rows",rows[i]);
            String row  = rows[i];
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            final String[] cols = row.split(";");

            Log.i(LOG_CLASS, "<<---- Columns count : " + cols.length + " ---->>");

            for (int j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
                final String col = cols[j];
                TextView columsView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                columsView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_header);
                columsView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                columsView.setTextColor(color.white);
                columsView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,15);
                columsView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                columsView.setText(String.format("%7s", col));
                Log.d("Cols", String.format("%7s", col));
                tableRow.addView(columsView);
            }
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

        }

        tableLayout.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Using ViewGroup has no effect on this issue. The textview contents are still invisible

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a weight of 1 to it:

```
tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
```

Setting the weight on a TableRow solved another layout issue I saw recently.  So, it is worth a shot.

Comment: Hi Rick. please read my updated findings. the contents are actually present on the UI, but simply not visible. No idea why the opacity related issues are cropping up inside